# Is AMO browser compatibility logic officially documented?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, compatibility, user-agent

I am using PureBrowser 52.8.1, a fork of Firefox ESR, with `general.useragent.compatMode.firefox` set to True. My user agent string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 \
Firefox/52.0 PureBrowser/52.8.1
```

When I visit an extension page on addons.mozilla.org (AMO), for example [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/), I cannot install the extension because the installation button is replaced with a "Only with Firefox - Get Firefox Now" button.

Previously setting `general.useragent.compatMode.firefox` resolved this problem, but this is no longer the case. I can still install (legacy) extensions manually, so I know it *should* still be possible to install them from the website.

Is there an official document explaining how AMO determines if the browser is compatible? (Readable code also acceptable.)

Comment: It looks like PureBrowser is rebranded Firefox with non-open source stuff removed and some security extensions added.  It's bundled with PureOS but doesn't appear to be downloadable separately.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's correct, I'll find a better link, although the question is really about AMO

Comment: Yeah, don't worry too much about the link (I just deleted it).  As you say, it's really about AMO, and I couldn't find anything more substantive than what's in my comment for PureBrowser.